# Calculating the optimum timer interval (timer_settime)

Tags: c, linux, timer, intervals

In Linux API timer_settime, we all know that we can set the timer interval using the API timer_settime. The minimum value we can set is 1 ns, but it is not necessary that the CPU will take this, because it depends a lot on the frequency of the CPU too.

I want to calculate this and set this optimum interval to my timer (which should be least).

Any ideas how to calculate this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The optimum interval is *"as long as possible, given the constraints of your application"*.  In other words, don't fire any more often than you need to.

Comment: That is what we need to measure, and how. We need to set it to the least permissible value accepted by our processor.

Comment: The minimum delay you can get is obviously to call your function in a tight loop, without using the timer API at all.  The question appears to be ill-specified.

Comment: what more details/specifications you need? Please let me know, i will clear it. I don't know it is quite straight forward but you are not understanding it.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Perhaps it might help if you describe the end goal that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @caf: We work on ARM targets, where i have implemented a timer in a test tool. We need to set the timer interval to least permissible value, so that the user can set the timer expiry as per his needs and still get the results. Thing is: If timer interval is high, then chances are execution of test program can end before the timer tick. 2) If the interval is very low (like 1ns), then even though the API takes 1 ns value, but chances are the ARM processor may not accept the 1 ns value. That is why i wish to measure, what is the optimum least timer interval that can be safely put.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: It is not a question of the processor "accepting" the value.  If you pass 1 ns as the interval, then the timer will fire after *no less than* 1 ns has passed, which is what happens for all other intervals too.  If the processor cannot fire timer events that quickly, then they will simply happen as fast as they can.

Comment: @caf: Do you have any way to measure that? As what is the actual interval processor is taking, if we give 1 ns as the interval? Also in embedded systems, we can't abruptly set a value, as the system can crash..we need to be definite as what to set.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: If you need to know the time when you awake, you can either call `clock_gettime()` or you can call `timer_getoverrun()` to see how many wakeups you missed.  The actual wakeup time cannot usually be predicted in advance - it will likely vary from one instance of the timer to the next.  If you simple want to time how long the test takes, then forget about timers and just call `clock_gettime()` before and after the test.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Why do you not use the `times` sycall then? Call it once before `waitpid` and once after. The difference is the real time and CPU time spent in the child -- minus the overhead of one syscall (see documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "man clock_getres"?

Also, don't forget that there's a kernel and a C library between the caller and the CPU.  I think what you really want to know is "what is the shortest interval I can put my process to sleep for inside the kernel?"  I'm not sure, but that may depend on the clocksource being used by the kernel (which is only somewhat related to the clockid_t you pass to the timer_* and clock_* functions).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the kernel 3.15 will support [deferred timers](http://lwn.net/Articles/588086/). Should be exactly what you are looking for.